# Inject HTTP request header as managed property into managed bean

Tags: jsf, dependency-injection, jsf-2, http-headers, java-ee-6

Does JSF allow to inject HTTP request headers into a `@ManagedBean`, using `@ManagedProperty` and some EL expression?

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class MyBean {
    @ManagedProperty("#{headers.User-Agent}") // ???
    String userAgent;
}
```

I am using JSF 2.0.

Comment: Yes it does. But your example contains a logic error. You should use exactly the same EL expression as you would use in a normal XHTML page (i.e. just specify `'User-Agent'` as a normal string key on the `headers` map instead of the `User` header substracted with `Agent` variable parsed as a number). Perhaps that's after all your *actual* problem?

Comment: Thanks! The correct EL expression should be `#{headers['User-Agent']}`, right?